# full text search near not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm using a full text index over a column, the index is populated (full population).
The text inside the column are varchar(max) portuguese reviews.

I think all queries should return the same, but they not:

```
    select
        *
    from reviews
    where
        contains (ds_review, 'word1 NEAR word2')

    (returns 0 rows)

    select
        *
    from reviews
    where
        ds_review like '%word1 word2%'

    (returns 1 row)

    select
        *
    from reviews
    where
        contains (ds_review, ' word1 and word2 ')

    (returns 0 row)

    row:
    word1 word2
```

Comment: What do the 10 results look like? I would expect the second one to match `someprefixword1 word2` but not the first to do so for example

Comment: can you answer my question? I'm not going to bother explaining it if it doesn't apply.

Comment: Like I said: I think both queries should return the same, but they not.

Comment: OK based on results you say you are getting my earlier comment doesn't apply then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

For portuguese, "melhor", in this sample "word1", is a noise word. Creating a custom stoplist removing "melhor" and "melhores" from the noise words solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from reviews where ds_review like '%word1 word2%'
```

the % infront of  word1 would works like a wildcard making it *_*_word1 where the blank is anything as long as after the blank, the word matches with word1 like a prefix. %fix might give you the result unfix.

for more information, you can visit here
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp